# What is the fastest/easiest way to tell if 2 records in the same SQL table are different?

Tags: sql

I want to be able to compare 2 records in the same SQL table and tell if they are different. I do not need to tell what is different, just that they are different.

Also, I only need to compare 7 of 10 columns in the records. ie.) each record has 10 columns but I only care about 7 of these columns.

Can this be done through SQL or should I get the records in C# and hash them to see if they are different values?

Comment: In a table with a `PRIMARY KEY`, no two rows should ever be identical.

Comment: @ypercube But 7 out of 10 fields could.

Comment: @Branko: Yeah, the "tell if 2 records are different" in the title made me think he meant identical or not. Still it's poorly wriiten question. If one changes the definition of "different", everyhing can happen.

Comment: Lots of good answers, Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a group by query like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, .... field7, COUNT(*)
FROM table
[WHERE primary_key = key1 OR primary_key = key2]
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3, .... field7
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

That way you get all records with same values for field 1 to 7, along with the number of occurrences.

Add the part between brackets to limit your search for duplicates, either with OR, or with IN (...).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but not really what I am looking for. I need to specifically compare 2 records to see if they are different/equal. I do not want all equal records.

Comment: @Mausimo Just add `WHERE` clause to limit the query to these two rows then.

Comment: Ok, assuming your table does have a primary key (can't imagine otherwise), add a where primary_key = 1 or primary_key = 2, just before the group by.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Col1, Col2, ColEtc...
            from MyTable
            where condition1
           EXCEPT SELECT Col1, Col2, ColEtc...
            from MyTable
            where condition2)
 BEGIN
    --  Query returns all rows from first set that are not column for column
    --  also in the second (EXCEPT) set.  So if there are any, there will be
    --  rows returned, which meets the EXISTS criteria. Since you're only
    --  checking EXISTS, SQL doesn't actually need to return columns.

 END
```

Answer (score 1):

No hash is necessary. Normal equality comparison is enough:

```
select isEqual = case when t1.a <> t2.a or t1.b <> t2.b bbb then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: This approach becomes problematic with columns that are allowed to contain NULL

Comment: Can be fixed using explicit tests for null. I left that out because it makes the expression very nasty. It is still the right approach though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (a.column1, a.column2, ..., a.column7) 
            = (b.column1, b.column2, ..., b.column7)
         THEN 'all 7 columns same'
         ELSE 'one or more of the 7 columns differ'
    END AS result
FROM tableX AS a
  JOIN tableX AS b
    ON  t1.PK = @PK_of_row_one
    AND t2.PK = @PK_of_row_two
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the DISTINCT keyword? All duplicates will not be returned, so each row you receive is unique (and different from the others).

http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL

So you could make this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x,y,z FROM RandomTable WHERE x = something
```

Which will only return one row for each unique x,y,z combination.